# Cannot display a dot in the application start taskbar tooltip

Tags: qt, tooltip, taskbar

I am developing a Qt application and I encountered this problem.

I want the application shortcut from the start taskbar to display the tooltip: "MyApp V1.10" but it does display only "MyApp V1". The problem is that it does not display the dot and what follows it.

The tooltip text is the same with the FileDescription. It can be set in rc file.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code?

Comment: you can use any executable. in the rc file set the "FileDescription" to contain a "." (dot). Then start the application, pin it to the taskbar, close it and then hover the mouse on the icon.You will see that the dot and after it nothing is displayed. Windows caches the tooltips in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache - you might want to delete it from here.